# ImportError when running catkin_make_isolated

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the [source installation](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Source) on Debian Stretch on an armel platform.  When I come to the final step of running catkin_make_isolated, I get the following error:

```
$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated", line 12, in <module>
    from catkin.builder import build_workspace_isolated
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 66, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.terminal_color import ansi, disable_ANSI_colors, fmt, sanitize
ImportError: No module named terminal_color
```

It seems this is due to a version mismatch, but I'm not sure where exactly.
I'm running this in a Docker file, so it should be very reproducible:

```
FROM ev3dev/ev3dev-stretch-ev3-generic

RUN echo "robot ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

RUN apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends python-rosdep python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool python-rosinstall build-essential 

RUN rosdep init
USER robot
RUN rosdep update

RUN mkdir /home/robot/ros_catkin_ws
WORKDIR /home/robot/ros_catkin_ws

RUN rosinstall_generator robot --rosdistro melodic --deps --exclude roslisp --tar > melodic-robot.rosinstall
RUN wstool init -j8 src melodic-robot.rosinstall

RUN rosdep install --os=debian:stretch --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro melodic -y

RUN ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294146/importerror-when-running-catkin_make_isolated/) by [pepijndevos](https://answers.ros.org/users/35881/pepijndevos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2018-06-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-14**:
I can't check (as I don't have an arm board to run this on), but check that `python` does not point to `python3` in `ev3dev/ev3dev-stretch-ev3-generic`. Afaik all ROS Python pkgs are released for Python 2. If `terminal_color` has been installed for Python 3, Python 2 will not find it.

**Comment by [pepijndevos](https://answers.ros.org/users/35881/pepijndevos/) on 2018-06-14**:
Debian gives me a really old version of `catkin_pkg`. I did a `pip install -U catkin_pkg` and that soled that particular issue. But going full pip instead of deb, get me issues with roslisp that is trying to install packages that don't exist. How can I tell it to exclude that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Debian gives me a really old version of `catkin_pkg`.

Ah, I think I know what is going on. You're using Debian [upstream packages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages). Please read the page I linked. I'm not sure, but mixing this might not be a good idea.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0